# Draw a spiral in a box

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

[image: spiral]

This geometric spiral looks complicated, but it's fairly simple to draw; take the following box:

[image: box]

Draw a straight line between the corner of the box and some set distance above the next corner counter-clockwise.

[image: 1 line]

Continue this pattern inward, always staying that set distance away from the corner of the next line. Here's a few more lines in.

[image: moar lines]

As you can see, as the pattern continues, the spiral approaches the center and the boxes you draw begin to rotate. Note that the distance remains constant, regardless of angle.

### The Challenge

[The Inspiration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7DxlebZcrk) (and also thanks to the wonderful person who introduced me to this concept <3)

Given a numerical (possibly fractional) input from 1 to 25, write an image to disk that uses this pattern or display the output on the screen, where the distance from each corner is the distance of one initial side of the box divided by the input. Continue the pattern inward until the distance from the corner specified is longer than the length of the next side.

### Rules

- You may not use built-ins for this spiral creation, but you may use image processing builtins.
- If you write to disk, you must output an image in any of .jpg, .gif, .tiff, .pbm, .ppm, and .png.
- The initial side length must be at least 500 pixels.
- The initial corner may be whichever you choose.
- As always, [the Standard Loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/44713) are disallowed.

Comment: [Closely related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38436/8478)

Comment: Is there a minimum for how many levels deep this spiral must be?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I would never ask for an input greater than 25, I'll add that.

Comment: Including [.pbm or .ppm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) might help some of the less graphical languages.

Comment: [also related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110848/is-it-possible-to-draw-this-figure-using-mathematica#)

Comment: What if the screen isn't at least 500 pixels? Still no go?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ You may assume that the screen is at least 500 pixels. :)

Comment: @CoolestVeto Haha! I meant on a calculator whose screen isn't that large.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Oh! Well, if you're using TI-BASIC, feel free to extend the borders and just make it 500 _units_ tall instead. That's fine. :P

Comment: Is this about shortest possible code? I've read that nowhere, but the Shoes answer suggests so.

Comment: @BjörnKautler the tag [tag:code-golf] means that, yes.

Comment: Do I have to save it to disk or is displaying enough ?

Comment: @user7185318 It is sufficient to display the image.

Answer (score 13):

## [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/) (Ruby) 163 bytes

Shoes is a ruby-based GUI toolkit.

```
Shoes.app{n=ask('').to_f
r=s=5E2
a=[0,s*i="i".to_c,s*i+s,s,0]
(q=a[-3]-a[-4]
r=q.abs/s*n
a<<a[-4]+q/r)while r>1
1.upto(a.size-1){|j|line *(a[j-1].rect+a[j].rect)}}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
Shoes.app{ 
  n=ask('').to_f                 #Open a dialog box with no message, get n from user
  r=s=5E2                        #Initialize s to sidelength=500. r can be initialized to any vale, we use the same one for convenience.
  a=[0,s*i="i".to_c,s*i+s,s,0]   #intialize array a with 5 points needed to draw a square, in complex number format (first point=0 is duplicated.)

  (
    q=a[-3]-a[-4]                #find the vector from point plotted 4 before to the following point (plotted 3 before)
    r=q.abs/s*n                  #r is the scale factor
    a<<a[-4]+q/r                 #add a new point derived from a[-4] by moving toward a[-3] by a distance s/n 
  )while r>1                     #break loop when length of line is less than s/n

  1.upto(a.size-1){|j|           #for all points except 1st and last one
    line *(a[j-1].rect+a[j].rect)#take the two complex numbers correspondimg to the current and previous point,
  }                              #convert to 2-element arrays (rectangular coordinates
}                                #combine to make a 4-element array, use * to splat into 4 parameters, and draw using the line method.
```

**Outputs n=4 and n=25**

[image]

Note that the shape always ends in a triangle, which collapses further to a line. Replacing `size-1` with `size` makes no difference to the appearance of the output and would save 2 bytes, but I left it in for theoretical correctness.

**Output n=300**

Inspired by a comment by OP, the higher numbers do look great!

[image]

Comment: Is the space following `line` in the bottom line necessary?

Comment: @CoolestVeto unfortunately yes. the `*` converts the four element array formed by conversion of the complex numbers into four parameters for `line`. The standard syntax is `line(*(a[j-1].rect+a[j].rect))` so removing the parentheses and adding a space is already  a saving of one byte. Removing the space makes Ruby try to multiply `line` by the contents of the parentheses, which makes no sense and causes it to throw an error. There is some golfing to be done here, just not that. I'll look into it later.

Comment: I'm almost certain you can get rid of the parens around the argument to `upto`. Also, have you tried removing the `('')` after `ask`? I haven't tested it, but it may be unnecessary

Comment: @QPaysTaxes unfortunately neither of those works.

Comment: The output for 100 is _beautiful_.

Comment: @CoolestVeto I find n=100 a little disturbing; it jumps out and goes all 3D on me. I've posted n=300 which is darker overall and therefore calmer.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <s>1056</s> <s>1005</s> <s>985</s> <s>948</s> <s>522</s> <s>508</s> <s>507</s> <s>504</s> <s>502</s> <s>501</s> <s>493</s> <s>492</s> <s>488</s> <s>474</s> <s>465</s> 458 bytes

```
import java.awt.*;interface G{static void main(String[]a){new Frame(){int s=499,o=s,e,i,x,y;{o/=new Float(a[0]);add(new Component(){public void paint(Graphics g){g.drawRect(0,0,s,s);int[]p={s,s,s,0,0,0,0,s};for(double d=s,t;d>o;t=o/d,i=e*2,x=(int)((1-t)*p[i]+t*p[(2+i)%8]+.5),y=(int)((1-t)*p[1+i]+t*p[(3+i)%8]+.5),g.drawLine(p[(6+i)%8],p[(7+i)%8],x,y),p[i]=x,p[1+i]=y,e=++e%4,i=e*2,x=p[(2+i)%8]-p[i],y=p[(3+i)%8]-p[1+i],d=Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y));}});show();}};}}
```

Thanks to CoolestVeto and ECS for yet other ways to reduce size. :-)

Comment: Ok, I golfed it down a bit, but there is more possible for sure, I coded too object-oriented to be character-minimalistic :-D

Comment: @AlexA. If I later on improve my code and make it shorter, can i then simply update the post with the shorter version?

Comment: @BjörnKautler Yup, that's good! :) I'm working on a few places to shorten right now.

Comment: @BjörnKautler You certainly can!

Comment: Is it ok if the user has to enlarge the window to see the complete output, or does the window has to be large enough to show the output?

Comment: @BjörnKautler I don't see an issue with that. Removing the .pack()?

Comment: You can remove my "suggested edit" thingy if you want and just let that be the code, if you desire.

Comment: Yep, I meant the pack. :-)

Comment: I'll let it there for now, but I think I'm already way shorter. Most probably nowhere near the Shoes answer, but definitely shorter. :-)

Comment: Hm, how much rounding error is acceptable? Through size-optimizations my center is off the middle, the more the higher the input is. Replaced some Math.round() by (int)

Comment: I think now there is not much more possible without a different algorithm or with introducing the rounding error, removing the x/y rounding. @CoolestVeto you are welcome to golf it more if you can now. :-)

Comment: Wow, I've never seen more than 500 bytes chucked off an answer. :O

Comment: Ah, the good old deprecated `show()`, thanks. Calculate in the first post, there it was 7959 :-D

Comment: You can use `new Float(a[0])` instead of `Float.parseFloat(a[0])`

Comment: @ECS ah, good point, thanks, answer updated

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, <s>412</s> <s>411</s> <s>403</s> 398 bytes

```
import java.awt.*
new Frame(){
def s=499,o=s/(args[0]as float),e=0,i,a,b,d,t
{add new Component(){void paint(Graphics g){g.drawRect 0,0,s,s
p=[s,s,s,0,0,0,0,s]
for(d=s;d>o;d=Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b)){t=o/d
i=e*2
a=(int)((1-t)*p[i]+t*p[(2+i)%8]+0.5)
b=(int)((1-t)*p[1+i]+t*p[(3+i)%8]+0.5)
g.drawLine p[(6+i)%8],p[(7+i)%8],a,b
p[i]=a
p[1+i]=b
e=++e%4
i=e*2
a=p[(2+i)%8]-p[i]
b=p[(3+i)%8]-p[1+i]}}}
show()}}
```

Comment: I have problems to make it run with groovy 2.4.4  :  `Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static s.div() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Float) values: [25.0]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), wait(), run(), run(), find(), any()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static s.div() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Float) values: [25.0]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), wait(), run(), run(), find(), any()
 at s$1.<init>(s.groovy:3)
 at s.run(s.groovy:2)
`

Comment: With 2.3.9 it works fine for me.