# Filling space with pursuit polygons

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

Make a program which can fill a 2D space with "pursuit polygons".
The following picture will help you understand better what I mean.

[image]
You can also look up "pursuit curves" or [mice problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MiceProblem.html).

You can use any convex n-polygon you like
here are some examples

**Triangle**:

[image]

**Square**:

[image]

**Pentagon**

[image]

notice that for every polygon you can also use the "anti-clockwise" version of the polygon, which produces interesting results

[image]

Can you find a way to divide and fill a given space with pursuit polygons?
The result would look better if this could work with ANY convex polygon and not only the regular polygons that I used...

**EDIT**
I am new here, so I'll try some specifications:

**RULES**
You must fill an A4 page ( 2480 Pixels X 3508 Pixels)
You can use only triangles,4-gons and pentagons.(try some of them to have anti-clockwise rotation)
Fewest bytes wins.
Use at least 10 polygons and at most 20
All the polygons must be convex
The borders must be the sides of the polygons.So the polygons must fit perfectly in the given rectangular space.
The algorithm must create RANDOM patterns but you should try to keep the polygons all about the same size and make the polygons as regular as possible.

Sorry for the edits

Comment: Hi Jenny, welcome to PPCG. Your question needs an objective winning criterion. One possibility is popularity contest (most votes wins) but that would almost certainly get closed as an art contest. The other possibility is code golf (fewest bytes wins) but you need to make the output far more specific for that. Note that you can post challenges in the sandbox before they go live:   https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/15599 . Upvoting and temporary closevoting while you fix the spec to avoid invalid answers

Comment: (Just a suggestion - I think a tesselation of random triangles would be a good way to go for codegolf.) Be sure to specify minimum sizes and numbers of polygons whatever you do.

Comment: This is a really interesting idea for a challenge, but as mentioned it needs an unambiguous specification before it will be ready. One thing that isn't clear to me is whether the 2D space to be filled is specified as an input, or is a fixed aspect of the challenge.

Comment: There appear to be more interesting ideas here than can fit into a single challenge - it might be better as a series of different challenges on a theme. In addition to the mentioned sandbox, I recommend dropping into [The Nineteenth Byte chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) to discuss the different ways of turning the ideas into objective programming challenges.

Comment: The spec is looking much better already. What should we do at the edge of the canvas? Your examples have whitespace around them, because they are not rectangular. There are 3 possibilities: 1.Allow a border area of specified width 2. extend the design beyond the canvas, so the canvas becomes a window 3.make the design perfecty rectangular. Also - I think you want some randomness? You'll get fixed designs unless you ask for random, because random costs bytes. Specifying random can be a bit of a minefield sometimes though...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll make one more edit

Comment: @trichoplax related https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77492/15599 but the links cited there are even more related.

Comment: As Level said, randomness is a minefield. I'm not sure how to objectively decide whether an answer follows the requirement "*the algorithm must create RANDOM patterns but you should try to keep the polygons all about the same size and make the polygons as regular as possible*".